# TinyMCE is embedding raw tags in my site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just added tinyMCE jquery to my ASP.NET mvc project and when i tried it to add a post to a database and then display it. I got all the tags on my screen.How can i solve this.

```
<p>How are you doing?</p> <h1>Who are you</h1>
```

this is showing directly on my screen. How do i solve this.

Comment: how do you render it in View?

Comment: @teovankot I just used normal html tags like this  <p>@Model.PostContent</p>.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.PostContent)
```